# How to represent a *[]string in a graphql SDL language when creating types in schema.graphqls?

Tags: go, graphql

I am creating a graphql api but I am having trouble when using gqlgen for Golang,I need to represent this :

```
type Pets struct  {
    multiEan  *[]string
}
```

Into this more or less:

```
type Pets  {
    multiEan: [String!]
}
```

The think is when I run the command:

```
go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate
```

I get the golang struct representation given by the framework but not with the *[]string pointer I need, i get only a raw slice of []string, any ideas on how to solve it ?

Comment: Why do you need a pointer to a slice?  A slice is a reference type so I suspect, without seeing all you code, that you just need a slice. (Also gqlgen is a great package but requires a lot of work to understand - maybe try my package https://github.com/AndrewWPhillips/eggql)

Comment: I need to perform some validations that only work as pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Gqlgen generates the Go structs for you so you have to use what it gives you.  It does not make sense to say that I want it to generate something else given the GraphQL schema. You can adjust your schema to get different types but really you design the schema then work with the types that gqlgen has generated from it.

That said if your `multiEan` resolver should be nullable then you need and extra exclamation mark (!):

```
type Pets  {
    multiEan: [String!]!
}
```

However, since Go slices are reference types (can be assigned nil) this still won't generate a pointer to the slice.  If you need to use a pointer to the slice elsewhere then you can just take the address of it.  Maybe you could share a bit more code so we can see what you are trying to do.